# Async Sockets example which shows passing an object?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, network-programming

I need to create a server process which can push high frequency data (1000 updates per second) to around 50 client. I'm thinking the best way you do this is using async sockets with the SocketAsyncEventArgs type.

The client -> server connections will be long running at least several days to indefinite. I plan to have a server process listening and the clients connect and the server starts pushing the data to the clients.

Can someone point me to or show me an example of how to do this? I can't find any example showing a server process pushing an object to a client.

**EDIT**: This is over a gigibit LAN. Using  windows server with 16 cores and 24gb ram

thanks

Comment: You cannot make this work reliably on commodity networking hardware and operating systems.  You're off by about two orders of magnitude, at least without specifying what kind of latency and service interruptions you are willing to put up with.

Comment: @Hans Passant: You are wrong ;-) Async sockets can handle ten of thousands of connections. OS is windows server. 16 cores, 24gb ram.

Comment: This is not a connection problem, it is a frequency problem.  Put all 1000 updates together in *one* notification that you transmit once a second and you won't have a problem.  Google "Nagle's algorithm" if you're convinced that 1000 updates/sec is important, for example.

Comment: Yes  - I was going to push every 250ms

Comment: You can certainly reliably push TCP data to a client within a LAN at 4 updates per second, so long as the data per push doesn't exceed several megabytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use .NET Sockets to create this server-client project, then this is a good outline of what's needed:

Since the server will be transferring data to several clients simultaneously, you'll need to use the asynchronous `Socket.Beginxxx` methods or the `SocketAsyncEventArgs` class.

You'll have clients connect to your server. The server will accept those connections and then add the newly connected client to an internal clients list.

You'll have a thread running within the server, that periodically sends notifications to all sockets in the clients list. If any exceptions/errors occurs while sending data to a socket, then that client is removed from the list.

You'll have to make sure that access to the clients list is synchronized since the server is a multithreaded application.

You don't need to worry about buffering your send data since the TCP stack takes care of that. If you do not want to buffer your data at all (i.e. have the socket send data immediately), then set [Socket.NoDelay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.nodelay.aspx) to true.

It doesn't seem like you need any data from your clients, but if you do, you'd have to make sure your server has a `Socket.BeginReceive` loop if using `Socket.BeginXXX` pattern or `Socket.ReceiveAsync` method if using `SocketAsyncEventArgs`.

Once you have the connection and transmission of data between server and client going, you then need to worry about serialization and deserialization of objects between client and server.

Serialization which occurs on the server is easy, since you can use the [BinaryFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx) or other encoders to encode your object and dump the data onto the socket.

Deserialization on the other hand, which occurs on the client, can be pretty complex because an object can span multiple packets and you can have multiple objects in one packet. You essentially need a way to identify the beginning and end of an object within the stream, so that you can pluck out the object data and deserialize it.

One way to do this is to embed your data in a well known protocol, like HTTP, and send it using that format. Unfortunately, this also means you'd have to write a HTTP parser at the client. Not an easy task.

Another way is to leverage an existing encoding scheme like Google's [protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/). This approach would require learning how to use the protocol buffers stack.

You can also embed the data in an XML structure and then have a stream-to-XML decoder on your client side. This is probably the easiest approach but the least efficient.

As you can see, this is not an easy project, but you can get started with the Socket.BeginSend examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a.aspx), and the [SocketAsyncEventArgs example here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs.aspx)

**Other Tips:**

You can improve the reliability of your communication by having the client maintain *two* connections to the server for redundancy purposes. The reason being that TCP connections take a while to establish, so if one fails, you can still receive data from the other one while the client attempts to reconnect the failed connection.

You can look into using [TCPClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx) class for the client implementation, since it's mostly reading a stream from a network connection.

Answer (score 1):

First, some more requirements from your side is required.  You have server with lots of muscle, but it will fail miserably if you don't do what has to be done.

1. can the client live without some of the data?  I mean, does the stream of the data need to reach other side in proper order, without any drops?
2. how big is 'the data'?  few bytes or?
3. fact: scheduling interval on windows is 10 msec.
4. fact: no matter WHEN you send, clients will receive it depending on lots of stuff - network config, number of routers in-between, client processor load, and so on.  so you need some kind of timestamping here

Depending on all this, you could design a priority queue with one thread servicing it and sending out UDP datagrams for each client.  Also, since (4) is in effect, you can 'clump' some of your data together and have 10 updates per second of 100 data.

If you want to achieve something else, then LAN will be required here with lots of quality network equipment.

Comment: Transport needs to be order and guarantee so udp won't do.

Comment: This is over a gigibit LAN. Using windows server with 16 cores and 24gb ram

Comment: Well, that leaves you with TCP, and TCP won't allow you that what you are trying to do - sending 1000 somethings in a second - it has its own buffers and will repack the data as it seems fit.  You will have to lose some requirements, unfortunately.

Comment: After reading a comment about the GIGABIT LAN, I am sure that UDP is the only way to go.  Try to do anything from one comp to another using TCP and you'll see that timing of the data arrival is broken.  What is the size of one 'data'?

Answer (score 0):

What about rendezvous or 29 west? It would save reinventing the wheel. Dunno about amqp or zeromq they might work fine too....